# Openpyxl - How to read only one column from Excel file in Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to pull only column A from my spreadsheet. I have the below code, but it pulls from all columns.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb=load_workbook("/home/ilissa/Documents/AnacondaFiles/AZ_Palmetto_MUSC_searchterms.xlsx", use_iterators=True)
sheet_ranges=wb['PrivAlert Terms']

for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=1): 
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
```

Answer (score 27):

this is an alternative to previous answers in case you whish read one or more columns using openpyxl

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('origin.xlsx')
first_sheet = wb.get_sheet_names()[0]
worksheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)

#here you iterate over the rows in the specific column
for row in range(2,worksheet.max_row+1):  
    for column in "ADEF":  #Here you can add or reduce the columns
        cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
        worksheet[cell_name].value # the value of the specific cell
        ... your tasks...
```

I hope that this be useful.

Comment: did you mean: `for row in range(2,worksheet.max_row+1):` instead of `for row in range(2,worksheet.max_row):`?

Comment: Hi, no. Because worksheet.max_row return the highest index with elements on it, if you add +1, the last row it will be an empty line.  It´s possible to check for more examples here:[openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.html)

Comment: yeah, but for the function `range`, the second param is exclusive. This way we would miss the data from the last row

Comment: Aha, you are right, in my case the last row had a different value for the column, for that reason I didn`t notice the mistake, I will make the correction now, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Using openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
# The source xlsx file is named as source.xlsx
wb=load_workbook("source.xlsx")

ws = wb.active
first_column = ws['A']

# Print the contents
for x in xrange(len(first_column)): 
    print(first_column[x].value)
```

Comment: Using ws['A'] as to extract the column of sheet does not work. It thorws an Attribute error saying to iterate. Refer more for my answer in this thread below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754077/openpyxl-how-to-read-only-one-column-from-excel-file-in-python/70006361#70006361

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion is much simpler

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("your excel file")
source = wb["name of the sheet"]
for cell in source['A']:
    print(cell.value)
```

Comment: Using source['A'] as to extract the column of sheet does not work. It thorws an Attribute error saying to iterate. Refer more for my answer in this thread below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754077/openpyxl-how-to-read-only-one-column-from-excel-file-in-python/70006361#70006361

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd
dataFrame = pd.read_excel("/home/ilissa/Documents/AnacondaFiles/AZ_Palmetto_MUSC_searchterms.xlsx", sheetname = "PrivAlert Terms", parse_cols = 0)
```

If you don't feel comfortable in pandas, or for whatever reason need to work with openpyxl, the error in your code is that you aren't selecting only the first column.  You explicitly call for each cell in each row.  If you only want the first column, then only get the first column in each row.

```
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=1): 
    print(row[0].value)
```

Comment: This will still return one row at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ws.get_squared_range()` to control precisely the range of cells, such as a single column, that is returned.

Comment: get_squared_range() is depracted...  See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532026/get-squared-range-to-list-of-lists-from-excel

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple function:

```
import openpyxl

def return_column_from_excel(file_name, sheet_name, column_num, first_data_row=1):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file_name)
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = (column_num, first_data_row, column_num, ws.max_row)
    return ws.get_squared_range(min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row)
```

Answer (score 1):

By using openpyxl library and Python's list comprehensions concept:

```
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.load_workbook('testfile.xlsx')
user_data = book.get_sheet_by_name(str(sheet_name))
print([str(user_data[x][0].value) for x in range(1,user_data.max_row)])
```

It is pretty amazing approach and worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Using ZLNK's excellent response, I created this function that uses list comprehension to achieve the same result in a single line:

```
def read_column(ws, begin, columns):
  return [ws["{}{}".format(column, row)].value for row in range(begin, len(ws.rows) + 1) for column in columns]
```

You can then call it by passing a worksheet, a row to begin on and the first letter of any column you want to return:

```
column_a_values = read_column(worksheet, 2, 'A')
```

To return column A and column B, the call changes to this:

```
column_ab_values = read_column(worksheet, 2, 'AB')
```

Comment: ws.rows is generator and I am getting "object of type 'generator' has no len()" 
maybe max_row?

Comment: What happens when your sheet actually enough columns that there is actually a column 'AB' ?

Answer (score 0):

I know I might be late joining to answer this thread. But atleast my answer might benifit someone else who might be looking to solve.

You have to iterate through the column values of the sheet. According to my opinion, one could implement like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("/home/ilissa/Documents/AnacondaFiles/AZ_Palmetto_MUSC_searchterms.xlsx", read_only=True)
sheet = wb['PrivAlert Terms']
for val in sheet.iter_rows(max_col=1):
        print(val[0].value)
```

`iter_rows` loops through the rows of the specified columns. You can specify the arguments of `iter_rows` from min_row to `max_row` and also `max_col`. Setting `max_col=1` here makes it loop through all the rows of column(column upto the maximum specified). This pulls all the values of only firstcolumn of your spreadsheet

Similarly if you want to iterate through all the columns of a row, that is in horizontal direction, then you can use `iter_cols` specifying the from row and till column attributes

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer from ZLNK's response :

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('file_name.xlsm')
first_sheet = wb.sheetnames
worksheet = wb[first_sheet[2]] # index '2' is user input

for row in range(2,worksheet.max_row+1):  
   for column in "E":  #Here you can add or reduce the columns
      cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
      vv=worksheet[cell_name].value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('excel.xlsx', read_only=True, data_only=True)
sheet = book['Sheet1']
column_C_values = [cell[0].value for cell in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=3, max_col=3)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?