# get_squared_range to list of lists from excel

Tags: python, excel, readfile, openpyxl

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'C:/Users/test.xlsx')
sheet = wb['sheet1']
len=sheet.max_row
vals1 = [v[0].value for v in sheet.get_squared_range(1,1,2,len)]
vals2 = [v[1].value for v in sheet.get_squared_range(1,1,2,len)]
```

But I'd like to have such as

```
vals12 = [v[0].value,v[1].value for v in sheet.get_squared_range(1,1,2,len)]
```

Where vals12- is matrix with dimension (len x 2)

Comment: My current approach is correct, but I do not want to pass the cycle twice and create two lists. I'd like to have 1 variable

Comment: Don't name a variable `len`. It obscures the built in function of the same name, meaning you no longer can write `len(my_string)` or `len(my_list)`. It also confuses the readers of your code.

Comment: thx,  I thought it was the other way around will helps understanding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rows_iter = sheet.get_squared_range(1, 1, 2, sheet.max_row)
vals = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in rows_iter]
```

**Note:**

The `openpyxl` source code notes that `get_squared_range()` is deprecated and you should use `iter_rows()`:

> ```
>     @deprecated("""
>     Use ws.iter_rows() or ws.iter_cols() depending whether you
>     want rows or columns returned.
>     """)
> [docs]    def get_squared_range(self, min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row):
> ```

To use `iter_rows()` do:

```
rows_iter = sheet.iter_rows(min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=sheet.max_row)
vals = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in rows_iter]
```

Comment: `get_squared_range()` will be going away. Better to use `iter_rows()` or `iter_cols()`

Comment: @CharlieClark:  Thanks.  Updated answer.

Comment: I've also started listing deprecations in the change log https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#deprecations

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this might be:

```
values = [[cell.value for cell in col] for col in ws['A':'B']]
```

but you could also use `itertools.islice()` on `ws.values`